# Python-sdk-azure, Can we get the VM creation date and time?

Tags: azure, azure-vm, azure-python-sdk

I'm comparatively new to azure and I want to fetch the vm creation time using Python
I'm following this `"https://github.com/azure-samples/virtual-machines-python-manage/tree/master/"` repo and able to get the vm details, Somehow I'm not able to get the VM creation time.

Can anyone help me?

Current code to fetch the vm details

```
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential, Subscription_Id)

vm_list = compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all()
# vm_list = compute_client.virtual_machines.list('resource_group_name')
i= 0
for vm in vm_list:
    print (vm)
```

Comment: Please check this [So thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46720681/get-virtual-machine-created-time-on-azure-using-python-api)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get virtual machine created time on Azure using Python API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46720681/get-virtual-machine-created-time-on-azure-using-python-api)

Comment: Not really, I'm wondering how we can get the time of machine created for vm's, in the json response I do not see.

Comment: In the link above, "eventTimestamp ge '2022-06-26T00:00:00Z' and resourceGroupName eq 'testing'" this is the response i'M getting and tons of json data which does not have time stamp

Answer (score 0):

I can use azure cli to get the timestamp use below command

```
az vm list
```

This will list json data with fields and you can filter

```
date = vm['timeCreated'] //"timeCreated": "2022-06-24T14:13:00.326985+00:00"
```